# Format string exploitation, how to write memory?

Tags: c, security, assembly, exploit, format-string

I have the following simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Missing argument.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  echo(argv[1]);
  return 0;
}

void echo(char* arg) {
  printf(arg);
  printf("\n");
}
```

I'm compiling it with `gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32`. I'm also disabling ASLR: `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`.

What I want to exploit the format string bug on the printf function to do some ret2libc or shellcode-based attack.

What I realy need is to understand how %n and $n work for writing arbitrary addresses and the values on the stack. Can someone explain such syntax in detail with examples?

Thanks

Comment: The `n$` part is the argument index. It's optional and it lets you access arguments by an explicit index. In turns, this lets you access arbitrary locations above the stack pointer. `%n` is an output conversion that writes the current number of written chars to its argument. It writes an `int` but can also write a `long` or a `short`. You can combine it with the `n$` to write to arbitrary locations above the stack pointer. You can't write arbitrary large values, however, due to practical constraints. So you must overwrite only the lower part of an address.

Comment: As a bonus exercise you can also try with ASRL enabled, since `%p` should work as an oracle.